# How to particularize a word in string?

Tags: java, android, accessibility

I have written a simple code that Toast a message whenever the user types a particular word, for example, "help" and then it Toast a message

```
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    switch (event.getEventType()) {
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED:
    
            String string = event.getText().toString();
            if (string == "help") {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "we are here to help", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

I think the problem here is in the string as it is logging unnecessary words also as user types, is there any way how we can initialize the string for that particular word?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String string = event.getText().toString();

if (string.toLowerCase().indexOf("help") != -1) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "we are here to help", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: how can I add different words to it for example if I want to add a please word with the help 
word in it

Comment: it worked but, after I wrote "help" it toasted the massage but after that, with every other alphabet it keeps toasting the massage, can you please help